# How to change a color of element on click from a set of colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

Lets suppose I have a rectangular div called sun.

I have 4 colors for the div.

The colors are red, green, blue and yellow respectively.

The initial color is red.

What I want is when user clicks on the rectangle, the color of rectangle should change from red to green. When clicked again, green to blue, and thus on another click, blue to yellow and atlast when user clicks again the color should change from yellow to red and the cycle should continue. I can not implement such algorithm.

Answer is appreciated if if-else tree is used (although not necessary).

Comment: you don't need if-else - just an array and an index into the array to achieve the rotation of colours - like `let arr=[1,2,3,4], index =0` and then `someValue = arr[index]; index = (index + 1) % arr.length;` where you cycle it

Comment: @Bravo can you actually answer it please?

Comment: I would have, if you wrote any code yourself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Bravo comment you can use javascript array and add with eventListener

It rought but that it.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

const listColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];

let currentColor = 1;
box.addEventListener('click', function() {
  currentColor++;
  this.style.backgroundColor = listColor[(currentColor % listColor.length)];
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem have simple solution with js arrays and index check

```js
// DOM Element 
const SUN = document.getElementById("sun");

// Variables
let index = 0;

// Colors 
const COLORS = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];

// Handler
const initColor = () => {
  SUN.style.backgroundColor = COLORS[index];
}

const changeColor = () => {
  index++;
  if (COLORS[index]) {
    SUN.style.backgroundColor = COLORS[index];
  }
}

// Event Listeners 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initColor);

SUN.addEventListener("click", changeColor)
```

```css
#sun {
  width: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
</body>
<div id="sun">

</div>
<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using pointerdown? While this use case is probably far from production, it makes [pointer cancellation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/pointer-cancellation.html) impossible if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: so close - yet it doesn't loop the colours

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help, here's what I was suggesting in the comment

a simple array and an index into the array that is "wrapped" to 0 using the modulo operator

```js
document.querySelector(".tgt").addEventListener(
    "click", 
    ((colours, index) => 
        e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = colours[(index = (index + 1) % colours.length)]
    )(["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"], 0)
);
```

```html
<div class="tgt" style="background-color:red;height:64px;aspect-ratio:16/9">
</div>
```

Added benefit - NO global variables required